# Dynamic onclick Function

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I change onclick function of bottom code. I mean this **monogramposselect('1')** function. But not all of it. *1* between quotes. It should be changing on time. When I am writing some text to another text box, The "1" changes with the text. Is it possible?

```
<input onclick="monogramposselect('1')" type="radio" id="monogramkonumcep" name="monoramkonum" value="cep" />
```

Please take a look.

http://jsfiddle.net/ayhankerim/aW7H5/

Comment: You should create this function without passing any values. Just create a code which will capture the value.

Comment: "1 between quotes" is actually the parameter of the function...

Comment: for example, I write "stackoverflow" to the textbox, and '1' replaced with 'stackoverflow'. Thats what I want.

Comment: What do you call "textbox" ? Input type text ? Textarea ? Show us more code.

Comment: I'll prepare a fiddle

Answer (score 0):

In your declaration of `monogramposselect()` instead of taking in a parameter, have it use `monoramkonum.value`.

Answer (score 0):

**Maybe this can help you, or lead you to other ideas**

> HTML

```
<input type="text" id="event_1"/>
<input type="radio" id="event_2" />
```

> Javascript

```
window.onload = () => {
    const event_1 = document.getElementById("event_1");
    const event_2 = document.getElementById("event_2");
    event_1.addEventListener('input', (evt) => {
        event_2.addEventListener("click", function() {
            // you can use evt to do something, if you want to value, use evt.data
            console.log(evt);
        }, {
            once: true
        });
    });
```